# Subquery returned more than one value when using with inner joins

Tags: sql, subquery

I am using subquery with Inner Join and it is returning 10 rows but I need to match those 10 rows with another table.
How can I do that?

Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
    IT.IPTELM MOBILNO,TC.CDGACNTN GROUPACCOUNTNO, TC.CDCUSTN CUSTOMERNO, 
    TC.PRCARDN, TC.CARDNO, TC.CRDIND, TC.Limit 
FROM 
    CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 TC
INNER JOIN 
    CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF IT ON (SELECT DISTINCT CDCUSTN 
                              FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
                              WHERE PRCARDN IN (SELECT PRCARDN 
                                                FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
                                                WHERE CARDNO IN (SELECT * 
                                                                 FROM #T)) 
                                AND CRDIND ='P') = (IT.IPKIPN)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I think you should give us some information about your expected output and how it is your seems normal data ?

Comment: I have already tagged this to SQL, kindly check

Comment: @HarunKARATAŞ I just want to join the result from subquery to IPKIPN and get the result. But it is throwing error posted above

Comment: I think either derived tables or CTEs will make more sense for you. You're describing a join while actually using the join condition in an odd way. And here doesn't appear to be a relationship between TC and IT so why join there?

Comment: Faran Saleem, `SQL` is not a DBMS, SQL includes PSQL, TSQL, MySQL, OSQL, all are still SQL but all have differences in the language. You need to post what your DBMS is, MsSQL, MySQL, Postgress, Oracle...

Comment: Do you actually have spaces in yoru column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you support.
Actually my query was that i wanted mobile numbers of primary card numbers against secondary card number. 
And the scenario was I had two tables **CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801** and **CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF**. **CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801** had the columns like 'Sec_card_number', 'Pri_card_numb' and 'Customer_Number', In this table the Customer_number for 'Sec_card_number' and 'Pri_card_numb' were different therefore i needed to fetch 'Pri_card_numb' against 'Sec_card_number' and then the 'Customer_number' of that 'Pri_card_numb' to join with the other table **CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF** which had columns 'Customer_number' and 'Mobile_number'.
I have achieved the required scenario using below query.

```
SELECT SCD.SECONDARY_CARD_NUMBER,IT.IPTELM
FROM dbo.BI_SecondaryCardDetails SCD 
INNER JOIN CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 SC ON SCD.SECONDARY_CARD_NUMBER=SC.CARDNO
INNER JOIN CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 PC ON SC.PRCARDN=PC.CARDNO
INNER JOIN CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF IT ON PC.CDCUSTN=IT.IPKIPN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below :

```
select T.* from (
    SELECT 
        IT.IPTELM MOBILNO,TC.CDGACNTN GROUPACCOUNTNO, TC.CDCUSTN CUSTOMERNO, 
        TC.PRCARDN, TC.CARDNO, TC.CRDIND, TC.Limit 
    FROM 
        CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 TC
    INNER JOIN 
        CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF IT ON (SELECT DISTINCT CDCUSTN 
                                  FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
                                  WHERE PRCARDN IN (SELECT PRCARDN 
                                                    FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
                                                    WHERE CARDNO IN (SELECT * 
                                                                     FROM #T)) 
                                    AND CRDIND ='P') = (IT.IPKIPN)
) as T
inner join Table2 on your_join_condition
```

Comment: It does not serve the purpose. Still giving same error

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: What is this `#T` ?

Comment: #T has the list of card numbers, around 10 rows and 1 column (card_number)

Comment: What is the related between TOTAL_CDBS11801  and INPARTPF ?

Comment: Customer_number is the relation but it is a bit complex.. there are 2 columns in TOTAL_CDBS11801 Card_Number(Consists both Secondary and Primary Card) and Primary_Card, also there is another column Customer_Number. User will input Secondary_card and it will bring primary_card against that secondary_card entry and then It will pick the Customer_Number of that primary card and that Customer_number will be joined with the Customer_number in INPARTPF.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do everything in your ON, that's what a WHERE clause is for.

```
SELECT 
    IT.IPTELM MOBILNO,TC.CDGACNTN GROUPACCOUNTNO, TC.CDCUSTN CUSTOMERNO, 
    TC.PRCARDN, TC.CARDNO, TC.CRDIND, TC.Limit 
FROM 
    CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 TC
INNER JOIN 
    CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF IT 
    ON TC.CDCUSTN = (IT.IPKIPN)

WHERE TC.CARDNO IN (SELECT * FROM #T) AND TC.CRDIND ='P'
```

Allow the join to match everything in the column you want to join, then filter out the unwanted results with a proper where clause. You are getting more than one 'PRCARDN' from your subquery in your ON clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CDCUSTN 
    FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
    WHERE PRCARDN IN (SELECT PRCARDN 
        FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 
        WHERE CARDNO IN (SELECT * FROM #T)) 
    AND CRDIND ='P'
```

This is not guaranteed to give you a single result, as a matter of fact I doubt you want to otherwise only one row would ever have data from the second table, but you are using it in a way that requires it to return a single value, in an equality test. Run just that query, if it returns more than one value, and I wager it will return possibly 10, since you say there are about 10 values in #T, you can't use it in an equality test.

If you then need to join the results to a third table, this becomes a SubSelect

```
SELECT 
    ss.IPTELM MOBILNO,ss.CDGACNTN GROUPACCOUNTNO, ss.CDCUSTN CUSTOMERNO, 
    ss.PRCARDN, ss.CARDNO, ss.CRDIND, ss.Limit 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
        FROM CARDS.DBO.TOTAL_CDBS11801 TC
        INNER JOIN CARDS.DBO.INPARTPF IT 
        ON TC.CDCUSTN = (IT.IPKIPN)
        WHERE TC.CARDNO IN (SELECT * FROM #T) AND TC.CRDIND ='P') ss
INNER JOIN yourTable yt
ON ss.X = yt.Y
```